# Git, monogame and cross-platform development

Tags: linux, git, cross-platform, monogame

I recently started on a small project. We thought out a small game and are now building it. One of the most important aspects is that it works on Windows, Linux and OSX.

To keep things simple for a bit I decided to start development on Windows and convert the game to Linux later, expecting little problems; trusting the MonoGame framework. I am now in that process of porting but stopped very quickly as I ran into a major issue:

You cannot have both a Windows Game and Linux game in the same solution, it won't run.

I found out you have to start a new Linux MonoGame project and simply copy and paste the code into it. (Which is a terrible way to manage any project).

Working with git; I came up with the following

1. Ignore changes to all `.sln` files etc, purely keeping the code in the repository in such a way that the base directory is still in the 'root' project folder.
2. Keep all code in submodules and have the 'root' project folder branch out into windows, linux, osx branches to keep different editors' config files.

The only thing I found with google was [about the stuff I just described above](https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/452298). Does anyone have any experience with the issue I described or should I just try something and see if it's a proper thing to do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the platform, but can't you just create different projects which use links to the same files ?

Comment: @Amnon I was just thinking about that.... lol, I am going to try right now.

Comment: @Amnon It does not seem to be an option, the project-specific settings are saved inside the codebase itself. Meaning the output files will still be compiled as a WindowsGL exe file. What I do not understand is the very limited documentation from Mono itself, the compiled files are saved in a folder called `bin/Debug/<platform>/<executable>` giving me the idea that it is possible to have multiple configurations... but when I try to look for some options there's nothing to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you have 2 options. Either use code sharing as described in the Xamarin guidelines here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/

Or alternately, there's a more advanced approach using Portable Class Libraries (although not officially supported yet). I've got a description of how that works on my blog.

http://www.craftworkgames.com/blog/day-6-running-with-monogame-portable/

Neither solution is ideal but they are both better than copy and pasting code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see a lot of potential in your PCL solution, the 'official' stuff immediately led to solutions I had already thought about but thought were very hard to maintain because of symlinks, new files etc. Your solution will require some work for which I do not have the time for right now though, I will get back to this in the weekend.

Comment: @AmazingDreams Yeah, there's a lot of potential for improvement. I've had a dream of creating a C# engine that works this way for a while. Pretty time consuming though.

Comment: I tried to add that stuff and it compiles! I do, however, get a runtime exception. My setup is: `LinuxGame` extends `CoreGame` extends (XNA)`Game`. I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when `CoreGame` constructor calls `Game` constructor. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a pretty generic exception, although, if I had to guess I'd say you might be referencing the wrong DLL from each project. Note that each platform project should reference their platform specific MonoGame DLL and the portable project should reference the MonoGame Portable library. It's a strange configuration, but it does work.

Comment: Well I think I know what the issue is; `MonoGame Portable = v3.1.3-alpha`, `MonoGame = v3.1.3-alpha`, `MonoGame.Binaries = v3.1.3-alpha` yet does not include Linux packages. I got `net40`, `netcore` and `wp8`. Debian supplies no version beyond `2.5.0` (in `sid`). The 'support' from the monogame team itself is `"We supply alpha windows packages"` and I don't feel like managing the entire MonoGame source tree for a simple Linux binary file. I'm beginning to feel more and more like going over to Java.

Comment: I have decided to, for now, use/try LibGDX (or a similar project) until MonoGame has matured more.